# How to recover Google Account when I only have my email address and a YouTube Name?

Tags: google-account, password-recovery

I had a Google Account that I used roughly 6 or 7 years ago for PlayStation Store Purchases. Since I am trying to recover my account on PlayStation Network (PSN) I am now looking for that Google Account since it held the verification emails and account info that are required to sign back in.

All I have is my email associated with the account and the YouTube name that I used. I can’t recall anything else and since I have not used the account in over 6 years, it has been difficult for me to try come up with the password I originally used. Has anyone encountered this problem and, if so, how did you solve it?

Also, if there is not a solution it is not necessarily a problem. But I would just rather not repurchase media that I already payed for albeit 6 / 7 years ago.

Comment: Have you looked at the info on [Google’s official page on account recovery](https://support.google.com/a/answer/33561?hl=en)? If you had a phone number connected to that email, you could use that to assist in recovery.

Answer (score -2):

I would [contact Google](http://www.google.com/contact/) directly at 1 (650) 253-0000.